# How to hide method in logging chain with log4net?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, attributes, log4net

Say I have extensions to ILog. Currently when I use ILog extensions in my buisness logic I see `%method %location %class` properties as my Extension class ones. I want tham to be refrences to my business logic. Are there in log4net attributes to make ILog extensions hidden?

For example

```
using log4net;

namespace Helpers {
    public class MyObject {}
    public static class LoggerExtensions {
        public static void Debug(this ILog log, MyObject obj, string format, params object[] arguments) {
            log.DebugFormat(format, arguments);
        }
    }
}
```

for this `<conversionPattern value="%type %method %m%n" />` would return something like: `LoggerExtensions Debug message` and log4net would not care from where it was invoked.

I need some attribute to make this extension transparent for log4net stackTrace inspector. Is there any or how to create one?

Comment: Can you show your extensions code?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do something like this (note that I don't have time right now to test this)...

```
using log4net;

namespace Helpers 
{
  public class MyObject {}
  public static class LoggerExtensions 
  {
    public static void Debug(this ILog log, MyObject obj, string format, params object[] arguments) 
    {
      if (!log.IsDebugEnabled) return;

      log.Logger.Log(typeof(LoggerExtensions), LogLevel.Debug, string.Format(format, arguments));
    }
  }
}
```

The key to getting the right call site logged (i.e. where you call your extension method, not the extension method itself) is to use the "Log" method, passing it the type of your object where your logging extension is implemented.  Log4net will traverse up the stack until it gets to a type that is the same as the type passed to Log. Some refer to this type as the boundary type.  The next entry up on the stack will be the actual call site in your "real" code, not your logging code.

Note also that I check to see if debug logging is enabled and return early if not.  The Log method does not have a signature that takes a format and params arguments, so the message must be formatted before calling Log.  We don't want to spend the cost to format the message unless it will actually be logged.

As I said earlier, I have not tested this, but this technique is used when wrapping a log4net logger (for example in Common.Logging .Net) to ensure that the call site is maintained.  If you look for lot4net wrappers (or NLog wrappers) here on SO, the vast majority are not written such that the call site is maintained, so beware.  If you want to wrap or to hide log4net behind an extension method, you cannot simply delegate to the Debug, Info, etc methods.  You must use the Log method so that you can pass the boundary type.

Good luck!